# What is the correct syntax to use && and ! in an if condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is right syntax to check values based on `if` condition using `&&` and `!` operator?

I am getting an error and am confused by !.

main.js

```
if($scope.sysRecomm === 'High' && !($scope.busDecision==='21')){
    $scope.disableSubmitButton = true;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `!===`?

Comment: `!($scope.busDecision==='21')` will return the opposite truthiness of whatever the expression is evaluated as. If `$scope.butDecision` is 22 then prefixing it with `!` will give you true.

Comment: Are you having a type issue here, you're using === '21', is the value of `$scope.busDecision` definitely a string?

Comment: @DaveNewton well i suppose the main reason he shouldn't use `!===` is because it's not a valid js operator.

Comment: The syntax is valid. What is the error message?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Obviously a typo, but thanks.

Comment: *I am getting an error*. What error is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($scope.sysRecomm === 'High' && $scope.busDecision !== '21'){
        $scope.disableSubmitButton = true;
}
```

Comment: or just `$scope.disableSubmitButton = $scope.sysRecomm === 'High' && $scope.busDecision !== '21';`

Comment: thanks it resolved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

```
if($scope.sysRecomm === 'High' && $scope.busDecision !='21'){
```

Comment: Noting that `!=` and `!==` aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**&&** requires both side of the operator to hold TRUE to return true value of entire expression.

For example:

```
if(X && Y) {
 // this block is executed only if X & Y are true
}
```

Coming to negation operator **!** , it negative the truth value of whatever expression it is attached to:

For example if negation operator is used inside a if block:

```
if(!X){
// executed only when X is false.
```

}